# find command - list all directories with a set sticky bit

Tags: permissions, find, sticky-bit

#### This doesn't work

```bash
find / -type d -perm 1000
```

The problem is, that it matches only the **exact** permission (`1000`), but I only want to *find* out if the `sticky bit` is set or not. I don't care about the other permissions...

#### My solution so far

I feel that there must be a better way than this:

```bash
find / -type d -perm 1001 -or -perm 1002 -or -perm 1003 -or -perm 1004 -or -perm 1005 -or -perm 1006 -or -perm 1007 -or -perm 1010 -or -perm 1011 -or -perm 1012 -or -perm 1013 -or -perm 1014 -or -perm 1015 -or -perm 1016 -or -perm 1017 -or -perm 1020 -or -perm 1021 -or -perm 1022 -or -perm 1023 -or -perm 1024 -or -perm 1025 -or -perm 1026 -or -perm 1027 -or -perm 1030 -or -perm 1031 -or -perm 1032 -or -perm 1033 -or -perm 1034 -or -perm 1035 -or -perm 1036 -or -perm 1037 -or -perm 1040 -or -perm 1041 -or -perm 1042 -or -perm 1043 -or -perm 1044 -or -perm 1045 -or -perm 1046 -or -perm 1047 -or -perm 1050 -or -perm 1051 -or -perm 1052 -or -perm 1053 -or -perm 1054 -or -perm 1055 -or -perm 1056 -or -perm 1057 -or -perm 1060 -or -perm 1061 -or -perm 1062 -or -perm 1063 -or -perm 1064 -or -perm 1065 -or -perm 1066 -or -perm 1067 -or -perm 1070 -or -perm 1071 -or -perm 1072 -or -perm 1073 -or -perm 1074 -or -perm 1075 -or -perm 1076 -or -perm 1077 -or -perm 1101 -or -perm 1102 -or -perm 1103 -or -perm 1104 -or -perm 1105 -or -perm 1106 -or -perm 1107 -or -perm 1110 -or -perm 1111 -or -perm 1112 -or -perm 1113 -or -perm 1114 -or -perm 1115 -or -perm 1116 -or -perm 1117 -or -perm 1120 -or -perm 1121 -or -perm 1122 -or -perm 1123 -or -perm 1124 -or -perm 1125 -or -perm 1126 -or -perm 1127 -or -perm 1130 -or -perm 1131 -or -perm 1132 -or -perm 1133 -or -perm 1134 -or -perm 1135 -or -perm 1136 -or -perm 1137 -or -perm 1140 -or -perm 1141 -or -perm 1142 -or -perm 1143 -or -perm 1144 -or -perm 1145 -or -perm 1146 -or -perm 1247 -or -perm 1350 -or -perm 1351 -or -perm 1352 -or -perm 1453 -or -perm 1454 -or -perm 1555 -or -perm 1556 -or -perm 1657 -or -perm 1660 -or -perm 1661 -or -perm 1662 -or -perm 1663 -or -perm 1764 -or -perm 1765 -or -perm 1766 -or -perm 1767 -or -perm 1770 -or -perm 1771 -or -perm 1772 -or -perm 1773 -or -perm 1774 -or -perm 1775 -or -perm 1776 -or -perm 1777
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are interested in only one specific mode bit, you should be able to use either the `-perm -MODE` or `-perm /MODE` syntax. From the man page:

> `-perm -mode`
>
> All  of  the permission bits `mode` are set for the file.  Symbolic modes are accepted in this form, and this is usually the way in which you would want to use them. You must specify `u`, `g` or `o` if you use a symbolic mode. See the `EXAMPLES` section for some illustrative examples.

> `-perm /mode`
>
> Any of the permission bits `mode` are set for the file.  Symbolic modes are accepted in this form.  You must specify `u`, `g` or `o` if you use a symbolic mode.  See the `EXAMPLES` section for some illustrative examples.  If no permission bits in `mode` are set, this test matches any file (the idea here is to be consistent with the behaviour of `-perm -000`).

As a usage example, I created two directories and set the sticky bit on one:

```shellsession
test$ mkdir sticky-bit-test

sticky-bit-test$ mkdir dir-with-sticky
sticky-bit-test$ chmod +t dir-with-sticky/
sticky-bit-test$ mkdir dir-without-sticky
sticky-bit-test$ ls -l
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 user group 4096 Jul 19 18:55 dir-without-sticky
drwxr-xr-t 2 user group 4096 Jul 19 18:55 dir-with-sticky

test$ find . -type d -perm -1000
./sticky-bit-test/dir-with-sticky

test$ find . -type d -perm /1000
./sticky-bit-test/dir-with-sticky
```

As you see, both options correctly single out the directory with sticky bit set. As noted by @ilkkachu, the distinction between these two is further elaborated in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/749957/377345).

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm the current author of the *rawhide* (*rh*) program used at the end of this answer.

Note that the `/1000` notation works on GNU *find*, but not on macOS (and other systems probably). There you need to change that to `+1000`:

```
find / -type d -perm +1000
```

With *rh*, you can do this:

```
rh / 'd && sticky'
```

---

The `rh` command can be found here: [github.com/raforg/rawhide](https://github.com/raforg/rawhide)

Comment: It finds files using pretty C expressions. It can do everything GNU find can do (except -fstype) plus it can search by file attributes/flags (like immutable/access_only), and by access control lists, and by extended attributes (names and values), and by libmagic filetypes/mimetypes. The language is inspired by C and you can write your own search term functions (but it's a very very little language). First published in 1990. Lost for decades. I recently found it in my archives, fixed it, made it secure, and brought it up to date, and added everthing I could think of.

Comment: you can install GNU tools on macOS and they'll be prefixed with `g`, like `gfind`, `ggrep`, `ghead`...